# SQL Join 2 tables without a relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have the following tables:

Table1 with cols: A, B 
Table2 with col: C  
And I have a variable @d.

```
|Table1|             |Table2|            @d = 5;
 ------               ------
 |A | B|             |   C  |
 -------              -------
 a1 | b1                 c1
 a2 | b2                 c2
```

How can I display following output?

```
|  ResultTable   |
------------------
|A  |  B |  C  | d|
 a1   b1    c1   5
 a2   b2    c2   5
```

PS: I am using T-SQL.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: Cross join will be an option but will produce the product of the two tables.

Comment: @Eric: I oversimplified the question with a dummy example, since my actual stored procedure is over 800 lines and my question corresponds to a mini portion of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to give each row a number and join on that. This assumes both tables have the same # of rows.

```
select *, @d from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by A) rn
    from Table1
) t1 join ( 
    select *, row_number() over (order by C) rn
    from Table2
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: @FuzzyTree: Thx. And how can i join the variable d to it?

Comment: @Schwammkopf - Just add it to the `SELECT` list